# How to select datas for a particular user between a date range

Tags: mysql, php

I am querying a table with where condition in which i want to choose between a particular date range at present my query is like this with a where condition.

```
WHERE entered_by = '1' AND date_created = '2018-08-23'
```

I want to use a particular date range from to to how can i do this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82522/discussion-between-arun-vm-and-akina).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gWr5g2222yAE8Fh1Gc6Awf/5) shows that `candidate.date_created` data type is `VARCHAR`:

```
`date_created` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT ''
```

If so it must be explicity converted to a `DATE` data type when we use date literals in a compare operator and want to have a date type compare. Like:

```
WHERE CAST(date_created AS DATE) BETWEEN '$from_date' AND '$to_date'
```

Using CAST in the first operand forces the server to use DATE data type context. So all other operands will be converted to this datatype before compare. And the result will be one we need.

Comment: I down-voted this because there are at least three reasons why this is not a good way to handle dates and date ranges.  I cover them in my Answer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use functions on indexed columns.

Don't put dates in `VARCHAR`; use `DATE`, `DATETIME`, `TIMESTAMP`, etc.  MySQL does not understand tz info, as in `2018-07-16T09:48:30+00:00`; deal with it *before* storing into the date column.

Do test ranges this way:

```
WHERE date_created >= '2018-08-23'
  AND date_created  < '2018-08-23' + INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

to test for a week.  Note that you don't need to worry about leap years, etc.  For a single day, do use

```
WHERE date_created >= '2018-08-23'
  AND date_created  < '2018-08-23' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Do not use this (or CAST):

```
WHERE DATE(date_created) = '2018-08-23'    -- inefficient
```

because no index can be used.

So, if your query is

```
WHERE entered_by = '1' AND date_created = '2018-08-23'  -- original
```

change it to

```
WHERE entered_by = '1'
  AND date_created >= '2018-08-23'
  AND date_created  < '2018-08-23' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Note further:  This will work regardless of whether `date_created` is `DATE`, `DATATIME`, or even `DATETIME(6)`.  And it avoids the clumsy `23:59:59` (which won't be adequate for `DATETIME(6)`).

Also, have this "composite" index:

```
INDEX(entered_by, date_created)   -- in this order
```

A further note:  `BETWEEN` leads to the "midnight bug", wherein you accidentally include an extra midnight.  Note that my code has `>=` and `<`, not `<=`.